# ElasticSearch index referencing documents

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, documents

I am trying to make use of ElasticSearch to solve the problem described below:

I have one index for user profiles, where the users have control over their own profiles for example (typical website scenario):

```
    index: users / profile / 123
{
    "Id": 123,
    "StaffNo": 8378,
    "Name": "Joe bloggs",
    "Tel": "12345",
    "BloodGroup": "O",
    "Addressline": "1 high street"
}
index: users / profile / 124
{
    "Id": 124,
    "StaffNo": 8312,
    "Name": "Jane Fling",
    "Tel": "87878",
    "BloodGroup": "O-", 
    "Addressline": "2 church street"
}
```

I have a contact list index for every user, where the contact list owner can manage his/her own list and can only reference other user profiles as read-only (for obvious reasons).

```
index: user_123 / contact / 1
{
    "Name": "Seymor Totti",
    "Tel": "12345",
    "Addressline": "3 Maple Close"
}
index: user_123 / contact / 2
{
    "Name": "Marsi Pann",
    "Tel": "87878",
    "Addressline": "4 Lancaster Road"
}
index: user_123 / contact / 3
{
    "RefId": 124 
}
```

I would like the contact list owner to search using ES and bring back the following view of the data as these fields appear in both:

```
{
    "Name": ,
    "Tel": ,
    "Addressline": 
}
```

(And some profile elements are not for sharing)

The problem comes in where a profile owner changes its profile, I don't want to  make copies of that profile into every referencing contact list entry, it is the wrong thing to do, it should be only kept and updated in one place and then referenced.

My question is would it be possible to use Aliases and Filters to provide a simple search to the user to search through only his/her own contact list that can be viewed with the referenced data shown in the sample below? If so, please help me with the correct angle of approach to (efficiently) index and query.

```
index / user_123 / contact / 1
{
    "Name": "Seymor Totti",
    "Tel": "12345",
    "Addressline": "3 Maple Close"
}
index / user_123 / contact / 2
{
    "Name": "Marsi Pann",
    "Tel": "87878",
    "Addressline": "4 Lancaster Road"
}
index / user_123 / contact / 3
{
    "Name": "Jane Fling",
    "Tel": "87878",
    "Addressline": "2 church street"
}
```